# How to add the current month in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I have a script that I'm using to automate a small workflow but I am stuck trying to get the Subject to list the current month.

Here is my script:

```
tell application "Finder" to set selectedItem to item 1 of (get selection)
set theAttachment to selectedItem as alias
set fileName to name of selectedItem

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"(current month) as string Message from John Doe"}
    tell newMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file:theAttachment}
    end tell
    open newMessage
    get newMessage
end tell
```

Is this possible? I've tried searching online and in Script Debugger but I keep coming up short. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Microsoft Outlook, so I'm going to assume that your script executes without error, but simply produces an undesired result, namely an new outgoing email with the words *"(current month) as string Message from John Doe"* in the subject line.

On this basis, to get your subject line to contain only the current month, find the relevant line in your script that contains this:

```
{subject:"(current month) as string Message from John Doe"}
```

and replace it with this

```
{subject:(current date)'s month as text}
```

If you want the subject line to include additional text after the month, as your original script does, then you can instead replace it with this:

```
{subject:((current date)'s month as text) & " Message from John Doe"}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You read my mind! I'll be more specific on the future. :)